# Access outer ajax parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, closures

I have a function with 4 parameter

```
function getToken(u, p, url, role) {
var that = this;
oururl = url;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/Base/getConfigUrl",
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: url + '?username=' + u + '&password=' + p,
            success: 'callbackFunc',
            error : 'callbackError',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }

});
```

and the call back function

```
function callbackFunc(resultData) {
// how to get the outer parameter
}
```

inside call back function I need to access role parameter I logged the `this` variable and i can't find anything

Comment: "I logged the this variable and i can't find anything" — `this` has nothing to do with the variables that are in scope (except when they are also globals (avoid globals) and you aren't using strict mode (always use strict mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, per se. The `role` variable does not exist in the right scope.

You need to refactor your code so that you can get the variable from somewhere that it does exist and pass it to the callbackFunc function.

See the comments inline with the code for an explanation of all the changes.

```js
function callbackFunc(resultData, role) {
  // Edit the argument list above to accept the role as an additional argument
}


function getToken(u, p, url, role) {
  var that = this;
  var oururl = url; // Best practise: Make this a local variable. Avoid globals.
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/Base/getConfigUrl",
    success: function(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        // async: false, // Remove this. You are making a JSONP request. You can't make it synchronous. 
        url: url;
        data: { // Pass data using an object to let jQuery properly escape it. Don't mash it together into the URL with string concatenation. 
          username: u,
          password: p
        },
        success: function(data) { // Use a function, not a string
          callbackFunc(data, role); // Call your function here. Pass the role (and the data) as arguments.
        },
        error: function() {}, // Use a function, not a string
        // contentType: "application/json", // Remove this. You are making a JSONP request. You can't set a content type request header. There isn't a request body to describe the content type of anyway.
        dataType: 'jsonp'
      });
    }

  });
```

Comment: thanks alot for the Hints , i can't make the success get a function with success because the response is much more like 
`callbackFunc({"TokenValue" : "4f21wGAACBEJLyanR4JFZQmSBahNKck6OCAuH"})`

Comment: The code in this answer will cause jQuery to generate a callback name and include it in the query string. Any decent JSONP endpoint will respect that and use that function name in the response. If it doesn't then you can tell jQuery to use a previously defined name using `jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackFunc"` (you should rename the global `callbackFunc` you have already though so that jQuery doesn't overwrite it with the success function).

Comment: I did try those udpates but when it access callbackFunc the second parameter is undefined even the arguments array is still haven't the second parameter .(I tried the jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackFunc" but it didn't work).
i will use any storage to set and get throw the request.